# Updating dataframe to contain random values that sum to 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This code :

```
data1 = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
        'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
        'three' : pd.Series([1., 1., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

thirds = pd.DataFrame(1 / 3, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

print(thirds)
```

prints :

```
        one     three       two
a  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
b  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
c  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Which is expected.

I'm attempting to change the df dataframe so that it modifies the series values so that they sum to 1. Closest I've got to is :

```
import numpy as np, numpy.random

data2 = {'one' : pd.Series((np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1).flatten()), index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
         'two' : pd.Series((np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1).flatten()), index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
         'three' : pd.Series((np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1).flatten()), index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

random01 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

print(random01)
```

Which prints :

```
        one     three       two
a  0.173359  0.143096  0.254052
b  0.078862  0.589361  0.700310
c  0.747778  0.267543  0.045639
```

This is fine for 3 rows of data but how to apply this same modification to N rows ? So instead of hard coding the values within the arrays, generate them dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate generic random numbers of whatever distribution you need (e.g. uniform at random), then divide the entire series by its sum.

Example:

```
# Generate 10 random numbers uniformly between 10 and 1.
random_stuff = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
# Divide by their sum
random_stuff /= random_stuff.sum()
```

Comment: can you provide an example ?

Comment: Sure, I've added one.